# Wordpress if is_page function not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to add a function to my Wordpress theme that will add content before and after each post, but not on any pages. This does not seem to work, but not sure why.

```
if(!is_page()) {
  function custom_content($content) {
    $content = 'before post content' . $content . 'after post content';
    return $content;
  }
  add_filter('the_content','custom_content');
}
```

EDIT: Solution I ended up with that does the trick for me, using `is_single` to only include on single posts. If you want to include on single pages use `is_singular`

```
function custom_content($content) {
    if (is_single()) {
        $content = 'before post content' . $content . 'after post content';
 }
    return $content;
}
add_filter ('the_content', 'custom_content', 0);
```

Comment: Have you tested to make sure your if statement is working at all?  Trying putting something like "echo 'testing';" at the beginning of the if statement.

Comment: `This Conditional Tag checks if Pages are being displayed. This is a boolean function, meaning it returns either TRUE or FALSE. This tag must be used **BEFORE** The Loop and does not work inside The Loop.` https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page

Answer (score 1):

You might be using it inside the loop. is_page() works only outside the loop.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page